# Why my code for format change doesn't work? (Format Rules)

Tags: output-formatting, summation

I want to write the following in mathematica

$$ (\sum_{k=1}^n a^2_k)$$

Now I've written this as an indexed variable

```
Sum[(a^2)[k], {k, 1, n}]
```

which in mathematica shows up as
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (a[k])^2$$
But I want this displayed as the Latex form, with the subscripts (*but I don't want to use the subscript command*) and I tried

```
(# /: Format[(Power[#[i_], exp_])] := 
 Subscript[(Power[#, exp]), i]) & /@ {a};
```

But I get an error saying

**"Rule for Format of (a^exp_)[i_] can only be attached to Power."**

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong with the **Format** command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but I don't want to use the subscript command" Why not?  `(a^2)[k]` doesn't make much sense for anything else than displaying an expression in a certain way, anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs , because I don't the fullform of the expression to have subscripts. But I just want it to be displayed that way.

Comment: I don't understand your comment because it is not a full sentence.

Comment: @Szabolcs , there is nothing ambiguous about that sentence. When I use FullForm[expr] on the expression containing things like the one mentioned in the question, I don't want it show subscripts in the fullform. I just want to use the Format command to display it that way. This question relates to the use of the format command.

Comment: "I don't the fullform" is not a full sentence.  I don't think a reasonable answer can be given unless you explain what you want in very clear terms.  `(a^2)[k]` is plainly incorrect in Mathematica.  Redefining the way `Power` formats is a bad idea. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with `#`. For these reasons, I am going to stop here.

Comment: My mistake, it was a typo. I meant I don't want the fullform of the expression to have subscripts. But I suppose that's very clear from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you want to do:

```
Format[a[k_]] := Subscript[a,k]

Sum[a[k]^2,{k,1,Infinity}]//TeXForm
```

> $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } a_k{}^2$$